# display one particular div of a web page inside a newpage

Tags: html

I just want to display one particular div of a web page inside a newpage.How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a webpage with only that particular div and use iframe imbed code.

```
<iframe>my div</iframe>.
```